# What are those black areas on top of model after clycles render? How do I fix it?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I am pretty new to blender, still learning the basics and all. I started following Blender Guru's donut tutorial and my cycles rendering turned out really bad (see picture). I can't find out what those black areas are and how to fix it. I haven't used textures yet, just the simple material definitions like color and roughness. How can I fix it? What causes it?[image]

Edit: Thanks for the answers. Here is the project file.

[image]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your shaders ( and maybe lightning ) aren't correctly configured. I say this because if it's UV wrapped, the dark areas are signs of a lack of lighting or inverted faces. Additionally you can see these darker pink ( not the black areas ) rings and arches on the donut within the pink areas and they kind of look like a chrome shader.

but

It also looks like its not UV unwrapped correctly or the materials are assigned a texture to complicated for it's shape ( without a UV map ).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That was my fist time oppening blender, so I didn't change any configuration. Is it possible that the problem are with my GPU? The GPU I'm using is pretty old to be honest.

Comment: That's a possibility but it would have to be pretty old like 2005 maybe even older. Also if it's a scene you downloaded its possible you need to unpack some textures from the materials/texture panel. I've downloaded scenes before in the past and had to do that or worse had to manually load the textures and what not.

Answer (score 0):

Check for objects in the *Outliner* that are disabled in the viewport but still enabled in renders.  It seems like a backup object you had created at some point and hidden.

[image]